# Place Holder or Suppressing Re-ordering

Tags: formatting, automation, placeholder

Using the for loop how can I print:

```
file0.jpg
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
file3.jpg
file4.jpg
file5.jpg
file6.jpg
file7.jpg
file8.jpg
file9.jpg
```

The closest code I came up with is:

```
For[n = 0, n <= 9, n++, Print[file : n .jpg]]
```

Obviously this will print above with extra extra `:` which is not what I want.

In Python this is easily done by formatting [a place holder]:

```
for x in range(10):
    print("file{}.jpg".format(x))
```

How do you do this in Mathematica?

Comment: Take a look in the documentation at `ToString`, at the string concatenation operator `<>`, and e.g. at `Table` as an alternative for your looping construct.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this,

```
"file" <> IntegerString[#] <> ".jpg\n" & /@ Range[0, 9] // StringJoin
```

or this

```
Print["file" <> IntegerString[#] <> ".jpg"] & /@ Range[0, 9]
```

or this

```
Do[Print["file" <> IntegerString[n] <> ".jpg"], {n, 0, 9}]
```

or this

```
For[n = 0, n < 10, n++, Print["file" <> IntegerString[n] <> ".jpg"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`StringForm` is very similar to printf (which is very similar to Python's string formatting functions):

``` For[n = 0, n <= 9, n++, Print[StringForm["file``.jpg", n]]] ```

The double backquotes serve as the placeholder for the subsequent strings or stringified expressions to insert. If you want to use more than one extra argument, then put an index between your backquotes, going from 1 to the number of other expressions you are passing to `StringForm`.

EDIT: `StringForm` outputs a "plaintext" format. To get an actual string you should wrap it in "ToString":

``` For[n = 0, n <= 9, n++, Print[ToString[StringForm["file``.jpg", n]]]] ```